# How can I access the element ID from a class, within an ajax function in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, autocomplete, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to use the typeahead script for Bootstrap.  It's working great, but I'd like it to be a bit more dynamic.  I'd like to run several auto-complete inputs on the same page without duplicating code.

HTML:

```
<input type="text" class="typeahead" name="person_name" id="person-search">
<input type="text" class="typeahead" name="city_name" id="city-search">
```

Basic jQuery:

```
$('.typeahead').typeahead({
    source: function(typeahead, query) {
        return $.ajax({
            url: '/ajax_lookup_script.php'
                + '?source=' + ###[HOW CAN I PUT ELEMENT ID HERE?]###
                + '&q=' + query,
            success: function(data) {
                return typeahead.process(data);
            }
        });
    },
    property: 'name'
});
```

The above doesn't work (obviously).  But if I set the class name to `.typeahead-person-search` and then create a new typeahead function that manually adds the source `person-search`, and another function entirely for `.typeahead-city-search`, then everything works fine.  I'd like to avoid having two functions when it's really just a variable that separates the two.

How can I put the element ID of the active `.typeahead` class into the `$.ajax` function?

Comment: Typeahead does not support a function in the `source` parameter, it must be an array. There is nothing in the source code that would do anything with your function. https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/blob/master/js/bootstrap-typeahead.js Is that what you mean by "obviously it doesn't work" ?

Comment: Can I somehow pass a variable from $(this) into the typeahead function, particularly the source parameter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I've gone up on something else, I couldn't test it directly with the .typeahead librairy, but I've done the same thing with another librairy I amusing.

How bout doing

```
$('.typeahead').each(function(){
    var self = $(this);

    self.typeahead({
        source: function(typeahead, query) {
            return $.ajax({
                url: '/ajax_lookup_script.php'
                    + '?source=' + self.attr('id')
                    + '&q=' + query,
                 success: function(data) {
                    return typeahead.process(data);
                }
            });
        },
        property: 'name'
    });
});
```

Comment: Perfect!  This is exactly the work-around I was looking for.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

EDIT :: try my second answer it should work, I've been using that with another librairy that had the same problem

try something like

```
var id = $(this).attr('id');
```

then

```
var url = 'blahblah' + id + 'blablahblah);
```

and put the var url in your ajax query at the url: spot

Comment: Yes, obviously. But for some reason this doesn't work from within the .typeahead function.  All variables tied to $(this) come back undefined within the scope of the function -- even using console.log($(this).att('id'));

Comment: Ill check it, there's not a lot of doc on it, it might be problematic!

Answer (score 0):

You could add a data attribute to each input that contains the dynamic portion of the URL.

```
<input type="text" class="typeahead" name="person_name" id="person-search" data-source="person-search">
<input type="text" class="typeahead" name="city_name" id="city-search" data-source="city-search">
```

You can then grab that using jQuery and pass it into the URL.

```
$('.typeahead').typeahead({
    source: function(typeahead, query) {
        var source = $(this).data('source');
        return $.ajax({
            url: '/ajax_lookup_directory/'+source+'.php?q=' + query,
            success: function(data) {
                return typeahead.process(data);
            }
        });
    },
    property: 'name'
});
```

Comment: Thanks.  I started with this one.  Unfortunately $(this).data('source') is not accessible within the typeahead function. I even replaced your `var source` line with `console.log($(this).data('source'));` to double check.  Undefined.  Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following

```
$('.typeahead').typeahead({
    source: function(typeahead, query) {
        return $.ajax({
            url: '/ajax_lookup_directory/' + $(this).attr('id') + '.php?q=' + query,
            success: function(data) {
                return typeahead.process(data);
            }
        });
    },
    property: 'name'
});
```

Comment: Thanks.  I just tried this, but it looks like $(this) is not passed through into the .typeahead function.  It comes back undefined.  What next?